# Set SVG color from background image cell?

Tags: svg, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I snagged some pretty material design icons and intend on using them in my Google Sheets to spruce things up a bit: [Google Sheet: SVG Icons](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G1qbCOYlOZvorh7TIC76o_m52BIzwfyNoDaDqksvITk/edit?usp=sharing)

Is there a way to change the color of an SVG background image from the cell?

I couldn't find anything in the Docs Editors Help page: [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en).

I'm currently using this to grab the image from my website and use it as a background:

```
=image("http://oneezy.com/www/icons/icon-star.svg",1)
```

Does anyone know the trick or will I have to make ten different icon sets with different colors?

[image: SVG Icons]

Comment: @Eric Koleda, I'm not sure why you removed my "google-apps-script" and "google-sheets-api" as I feel like they could be directly a part of making this  happen. I did add them back. If you feel like they still don't belong here, please explain your edit in further detail.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Your question doesn't mention either, so it didn't seem related. Happy to keep them on, but I don't think they'll help you find an answer.